# Error when installing node package?

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

I new in nodejs and have a error when run `npm install` in my project.

```
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\
node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "i"
npm ERR! node v7.7.1
npm ERR! npm  v4.1.2
npm ERR! code EBADPLATFORM

npm ERR! notsup Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.0.15: wanted {"os":"darwin",
"arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm ERR! notsup Valid OS:    darwin
npm ERR! notsup Valid Arch:  any
npm ERR! notsup Actual OS:   win32
npm ERR! notsup Actual Arch: x64

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\projects\rehouse\src\dd_rehouse_renewal_win\npm-debug.log
```

I don't know this error: `Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.0.15: wanted {"os":"darwin",
    "arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})`
Please help me solve it.

Comment: well "wanted os darwin (current win32)" sounds to me like whatever fsevents is, it wants MacOS and not windows. But im not familiar enough with node to know what to do about it :/

Comment: It may be version issue, see this tree https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/14042

Comment: Also try `npm cache clean` and then run again your command

Comment: Thanks all, i had fixed my problem after added `optional: true,` in my `npm-shrinkwrap.json` for fsevents and run with `npm i --no-optional`

Answer (score 0):

From [this](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/14042#issuecomment-251683306) discussion, I would try approach 1 first. If that doesn't work, try approach 2.

1. Add:

   `"optionalDependencies": {
   "fsevents": "*"
   },`

   to your package.json and then install with `--no-optional`
2. Try downgrading your npm version to the next lower stable version.